# Android collapsed menu item with icon?

Tags: android

I want to make 3 collapsed menu items for connecting with 3 different social networks , and i want to have a small icon with some text for each one.

how can I make the collapsed menu item show an icon and text ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("Option");
            sub.setIcon(R.drawable.more_btn);
            Spanned others = Html.fromHtml("<b>Other Apps</b>");
            sub.add(0, 1, 0, others).setIcon(R.drawable.other_apps_icon);
            sub.add(0, 2, 0, "About Us").setIcon(R.drawable.about_us_icon);
            sub.add(0, 3, 0, "Share").setIcon(R.drawable.share);
            Spanned audio = Html.fromHtml("<b>Audio Quality</b>");
            sub.add(0, 4, 0, audio).setIcon(R.drawable.top_menu_settings_icon);
            sub.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
            return true;
        }
```